# Drop column within function sparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

Say I want to write a function to delete a column from a SparkR DataFrame(Version 1.6.0):

```
dropColumn <- function(df, col) {
  df[[col]] <- NULL
  df
}
df <- dropColumn(df, 'Email')
```

But it would error out:

```
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, col, value = NULL) : 
[[<- defined for objects of type "S4" only for subclasses of environment
```

How can I change my code fix it?

Comment: Open JIRA, implement required method on DataFrame, make PR?

Comment: I mean there is not much you can do about it here. DataFrame simply doesn't implement `[[<-`.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no convenience method in dataframe for dropping a column. I think this would work for now until it could could be implemented in SparkR:

```
dropColumn <- function(df, col) {
    tempdf <- new("DataFrame",
          sdf=SparkR:::callJMethod(df@sdf, "drop", col),
          isCached=FALSE)
    tempdf
}
newdf <- dropColumn(inputdf, 'Email')
```